# Visual Studio Web Testing - Are there any good books/videos available?

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing, webtest, web-testing

I am trying to find a good resource on web and load testing. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 ultimate and, while i'm sure it is too early for much material to be released, i'm hoping there are some good resources for Visual Studio 2008 that are still relevant. While MSDN has some good information I'm looking for something more cohesive that i can view on my way to/from work - hence a book or a video
Thanks in advance,
JP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found this PDF, which might be of use to you:

http://vsptqrg.codeplex.com/

Update: here's a good video from MVC conf 2 which shows load testing in action
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf/mvcConf-2-Steven-Smith-Improving-ASPNET-MVC-Application-Performance

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look on this [guide on recording and correlating VSTS WebTests using Fiddler](http://www.bugtrap.co.uk/2010/06/using-fiddler-with-visual-studio-team.html).